# Which of the below python code is effective to convert yes_no type categorical variable to 1 - 0 encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, data-cleaning

Considering performance, effectiveness and other parameters, which of the below code is better to convert categorical yes/no variable to one/zero variable?

Code 1:

```
variable_list = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']

yes_no = {'Yes':1,'No':0}

for i in variable_list:
    df[i]=df[i].map(yes_no)
```

Code 2:

```
variable_list = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']

def binary_map(x):
    return x.map({'Yes':1,'No':0})

df[variable_list]=df[variable_list].apply(binary_map)
```

Comment: If only 'Yes' or 'No' are the only values in that column then you can just use boolean condition.  `(df[variable_list] == 'Yes).astype(int)'`

Answer (score 0):

While I know you are asking specifically about the performance of two approaches, I feel it is useful to let folks know that Pandas comes with a tool to convert data into categorical data. Once the data is converted to categorical data, you can access the categorical codes.

Let's make a sample DataFrame:

```
In [23]: import pandas as pd
    ...: columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame([['Yes', 'No', 'Yes'], ['No', 'Yes', 'No'], ['Yes', 'No', 'No']], columns=columns)
```

If we look at the data using `.dtypes`, we see that the data is currently stored as a collection of `objects`.

```
In [22]: df.dtypes
Out[22]: 
Column1    object
Column2    object
Column3    object
dtype: object
```

Using Pandas' builtin `.astype()` function, we can convert all the columns to a category datatype. Again, using `.dtypes` we can now see the datatype shows up as `category`:

```
In [24]: df[columns] = df[columns].astype('category')
    ...: df.dtypes
    ...: 
Out[24]: 
Column1    category
Column2    category
Column3    category
dtype: object
```

Since our data is stored as a `category` datatype, we can reference the `.cat.codes` attribute to access the categorical codes for each element. Since `.cat.codes` is a Series-level attribute (not a DataFrame-level attribute), we need to cycle through each column and do the conversion column by column.

```
In [25]: for col in columns:
    ...:     df[col] = df[col].cat.codes
    ...:
```

This yields a DataFrame full of numerical values.

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0        1        0        1
1        0        1        0
2        1        0        0
```